# Vuforia plane finder custom image

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I want to chance default image for plane finder but i cant find how,

[image: default iamge]

I am using Unity.

Comment: So...you want to change the image target?

Comment: it is not the same think/

Comment: I don't think Vuforia is allowing us to do that. And why would you want to do it anyway?